# I want to add functionality into my site that users may be able to sign agreement, pay, and then submit

Tags: users

I want to add functionality into my site that users may be able to sign agreement, pay, and then submit. Also I would like to use this data in the future...
Any advice??
EDIT: I want something like web form with payment option on it, I just want a user to be able to pay via Credit card, if the form is filled correctly and all required fields are good... Don't need HIGH-END commerce or online store ??? Please help :(

Comment: I think the question is clear enough... and it was resolved 7 hours before these people put it on hold... doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module to allow the users to fill it out and then use the [Payment for Webform](https://drupal.org/project/payment_webform) module for payment options.

> This module provides a payment reference Webform component, which
>   allows users to associate payments (made through Payment) with Webform
>   submissions. A possible use case is requiring users to pay before
>   submitting a webform.

***or*** you can do it with [Commerce Webform](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_webform) module, by following this [tutorial](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/commerce-webform) you can easily set up the payment options.

Comment: I have done exactly same thing, but on the form it says "There are no available payment methods". I have no payment methods at "Home » Administration » Configuration » Payments"
but at "Home » Administration » Store » Configuration" I have several... it is my first time implementing payment, any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Go to Administration » Configuration » Web services » Payment » Payment methods » Basic, and fill out the fields and read the entire document here https://drupal.org/node/1932450

Comment: This enibled "Collect on delivery" and "No payment required" and the one I made... the real question stays. My client want to process his payments through "HOSTED PCI"... I want to enable that one...

Comment: Here is the simple tutorial for https://drupal.org/project/commerce_webform - easy to setup http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/commerce-webform

Comment: You done with commerce webform  or payment for webform ?

Comment: Commerce Webform worked... payment webform is still mystery...